# Overhead of thread creation and deletion v/s unused threads

Tags: c, windows, multithreading

For developing a udp server that can handle maximum 'x' number of clients at a time, I have two options:

1. When the server is started, 'x' threads are created immediately without chechking if all the 'x' clients are active or not.
2. Second option is that when server is started, it waits for client's request and when a request from a specific client arrives, only then a thread is spwaned for servicing that client.
   If the specific client goes down, the thread dedicated to that specific client is also deleted.

In option#1, 'x' number of threads are created at the start even if there is only 1 client connected, only when thread will be utilized and all remaining 'x-1' threads will be suspended.

In option#2, it seems that I'll face the overhead of continuous thread creation & deletion.

I have decided to use option#2 for the implementation of my apppication but I am still confused if my choice is right or not.

Please help me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Use a combination of the two by implementing thread pooling.  Create a thread pool that is initially empty, or contains a number of initial suspended threads, your choice.  When a new client "connects" and does not exceed the max number of allowed clients, check if the pool has an available thread.  If so, re-use it.  If not, create a new thread.  When the client "disconnects", put the thread back into the pool and suspend it.  If a given thread stays in the pool for awhile, remove and destroy it.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the overhead of context switching *while* the thread is running. Using three thousand threads on a four-core CPU is going to introduce far more overhead than using four-to-eight threads on the same four-core CPU. Consider the resources that three thousand threads would use, in terms of stack allocations, versus four-to-eight threads.

It makes far more sense to handle as many non-blocking sockets as possible on a static, predetermined or user-configurable number of threads.

Answer (score 1):

Option 3 - a thread pool that can increase and decrease as needed or, ideally, not at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little confused what you are saying or, maybe, more information is required. Remember that UDP clients DO NOT connect they just send packets, and those packets are not guaranteed to arrive in the order they were sent.

What I would do is just have a listening UDP socket waiting for packets. You should maintain a list of valid clients either by its IP address or by any other method, an ID inside the packet's data for example. Once a packet is received you process it with a function/thread which handles the client's request. As I see it, you don't even need to start new threads but it depends what the server is going to do when a packet is received and how long it takes to process it. Also, remember that the function/thread which handles the request cannot receive more packets from the client (through the same port); all incoming packets are handed by the server thread. The function or thread that handles the client's request all it can do is sending one o more UDP packet to the client to acknowledge the request but it cannot maintain a conversation with the client, neither is able to determine if the client is down because there is no a permanent open connection. If you need a conversation between server and clients then you need to change to TCP sockets.

This is a draft of code:

```
ClientRequestThread(DatagramPacket packet)
{
    String FromIP = packet.getAddress().getHostAddress();
    byte[] data = packet.getData();
    // Here you must identify the client, either by its IP address 
    // or maybe an ID inside the data.

    if (TheDataHaveBeenProccessOK)
    {
        Send a positive acknowledge
    }
    else
    {
        Send a negative acknowledge
    }
}

ServerThread()
{
    DatagramSocket datagramSocket;
    try
    {
        datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(MyPortNumber);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Unable to open the datagram socket.
        // Handle it accordingly
        return;
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[256]; // change it to your needs
    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

    while (YouDontStopMe)
    {
        try
        {
            datagramSocket.receive(packet);
// Here you must either call a function or start a thread 
// to handle the client request
// depends on what you are going to do with the client's request.
            ClientRequestThread(packet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Error reading the socket, handle it accordingly
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    datagramSocket.close();
}
```